# Callback function for ng-if in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-ng-if

How to execute some code after completely rendering ng-if block in angular1?

```
<div ng-if="isEnableDateEntry == true">
     <input type="text" class="datapicker"/>
</div>
```

I want to execute the following code only after completely rendering the **ng-if** block

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker();
```

Comment: Practically speaking, I think you could just rely on the value of `isEnableDateEntry` in this case.  By the way, in general calling Jquery functions from a controller is a no-go, you probably have to do that from a custom directive.

Comment: This question seems to suggest some behavior of the AngularJs framework that doesn't really function the way you think it does.  It's not really clear what you are actually attempting to accomplish, but trying to do something "after completely rendering" some HTML doesn't really make sense for AngularJs.  This is definitely an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/297619) as currently written.

Answer (score 0):

Just use AngularJS Directives instead of manually initializing datepicker everytime in controller, because directives recompiles on eevery `$digest()` call. For your problem here is the solution

```
angular.module("moduleName")

    .directive("datepicker", function () {
        return {
            restrict: "C",
            link: function($scope,element){
                element.datepicker();
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: Actually I have to do many things apart from initializing the date picker, I want a common solution like ng-if render complete.

Comment: Dear, the link function in the directive is always called after ng-if

Comment: Thanks for the support, Yes. The logic you said is working in the case of the textbox, But when I created a custom class directive for dropdownlist (element.selectpicker('refresh')), its works. But the issue is, directive is getting executed before creating option lists. I am getting an empty dropdown list.

Comment: How r u creating options list

Comment: Option list is creating by using an ng-repeat

Comment: then use watch for options in directive

Answer (score 0):

### Directive to execute callback

```
app.directive("callback", function() {
    return postLink;
    function postLink(scope,elem,attrs) {
        scope.$eval(attrs.callback, {$element: elem});
    }
})
```

### Usage

```
<div callback="$ctrl.someFn($element)">
</div>
```

When the above element is rendered, the linking function will execute the specified Angular Expression with the element exposed as `$element`.